# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written a simple wpf application for binding data in datagrid. It throws error while running at following line.

```
string ConString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                         .ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ToString();
```

Exception shows: `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."`

`InnerException:{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

Comment: At which point in your application are you calling this line? If you check the value of ConfigurationManager, is it null?

Comment: I have written it in a method FillDatagrid()

Comment: Could you please provide a callstack for this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"] is NULL or
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings is NULL.

Comment: app.config file :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add   name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=HDDLNTD6021985;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2008R2;Persist Security Info=True;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: Why this is coming null.Still unable to find